# replace DescriptionAttr with Dictionary or smth

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a enum that's contain Description Attribute(for audit):

```
public enum ActivityType
{
    [NotExist("Not Assign")]
    [Description("Change Level")]
    LevelChanged,

    [NotExist("Not Assign")]
    [Description("Change Skill Level")]
    SkillLevelChanged
 }
```

And all had been great until i needed to put Desription in Resource files(attribute didn't support them), so i need Dictionary or something like this.The question is: How implement this feature without big changing in all another logic?Something like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<ActivityType, String> ActivityDescription = new Dictionary<ActivityType, String>()
    {
        {ActivityType.LevelChanged, "Change"},
        {ActivityType.SkillLevelChanged, "SkillChange"}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that requires the minimal amount of code change for you would be to alter your descriptions to be the resource keys in your resource file. Then you could read these dynamically by doing something like:

```
[Description("Change_Level")]
```

Then your resource key/value would be:

```
Change_Level             Change Level
```

And to read it you can do:

```
FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
DescriptionAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
        .GetField(value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;

if (attribute != null)
{
    var resManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResources));
    return resManager.GetString(attribute.Description);
}
else
{
    return value.ToString();
}
```

If however you're wanting a *nicer* solution with the option to pass in the resource file, you can hijack the `Display` attribute:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(MyResources), Name = "Change_Level")]
```

Then you can do:

```
FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
DisplayAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
        .GetField(value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;

if (attribute != null)
{
    var resManager = new ResourceManager(attribute.ResourceType);
    return resManager.GetString(attribute.Name);
}
else
{
    return value.ToString();
}
```